# big size multi image upload asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, size

I am working with asp.net c# fileupload with possibility of uploading multiple files. This is done with jQuery.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" class="multi"/>
```

More details in this link, where I found the source code:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68374/Upload-Multiple-Files-in-ASP-NET-using-jQuery

The problem is I couldn't upload files with the total size more than 5 MB.
The following error is occured in this case:

```
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET):
```

For example I want to upload files up to 30MB totally. 
Can anybody help to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MaxRequestLength:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx